# Is the UWP manifest element "uap6:SpatialBoundingBox" functioning for the HoloLens 2?

Tags: xml, uwp, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, appxmanifest

I have implemented a 3D launcher model in glb format following the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/implementing-3d-app-launchers). I am able to see the model in the Windows Mixed Reality home area, and the animations are functioning properly.

According to the documentation, the element [uap6:SpatialBoundingBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap6-spatialboundingbox) is available for computers running Windows RS4 (1803) or later. I am running Windows 10 Pro version 1809, Visual Studio 2019, target platform version 10.0.10240.0, compiling a D3D project for ARM in Release.

However, no matter what values I provide for the SpatialBoundingBox element, the launcher's bounding box viewed in the home area does not seem to change. For example:

`<uap6:SpatialBoundingBox  Center=”1,-2,3” Extents=”1,2,3” />`

vs

`<uap6:SpatialBoundingBox  Center=”0,2,0” Extents=”123,231,312” />`

I have found on some occasions that the documentation is either ahead or behind the current state of the Hololens features, so I wanted to see if anyone else has been able to successfully implement a bounding box override.

Sample manifest with identifying information replaced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:uap2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2" xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3" xmlns:uap4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4" xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" xmlns:mobile="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/mobile/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap uap2 uap5 uap6 mp" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5" xmlns:uap6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6">
  <Identity Name="EXAMPLE" Publisher="CN=TheEXAMPLECompany" Version="0.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>EXAMPLE</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>TheEXAMPLECompany</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18362.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="EXAMPLE.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="EXAMPLE" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Test capabilities for EXAMPLE." BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile ShortName="EXAMPLE" Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Square71x71Logo.png" Square310x310Logo="Assets\Square310x310Logo.png">
          <uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
            <uap:ShowOn Tile="square310x310Logo" />
          </uap:ShowNameOnTiles>
          <uap5:MixedRealityModel Path="Assets\My3DTile.glb">
              <uap6:SpatialBoundingBox  Center=”1,2,3” Extents=”30,20,30” />
          </uap5:MixedRealityModel>
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap2:Capability Name="spatialPerception" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the 3D app launcher feature is functioning for HoloLens 2. Please make sure your application is targeting a version of the Windows SDK greater than or equal to **10.0.17125** on HoloLens, your current target platform version 10.0.10240.0 is too low. Check out our documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/implementing-3d-app-launchers)

And thank you for calling this out, we found the `Extents` field setting is not working well on HoloLens, it should be intent to control the distance from the center of the bounding box to its edges, along each axis. We have reported this issue to product team via internal channel, but ETA cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The 3D app launcher feature is correctly working in my application even with the platform version (currently this version is required by company constraints).  It was only the modifications to the bounding box that were not working properly for us.  Thanks for confirming and reporting that an issue exists for the `Extents` field.  For others who may find this useful, we were able to implement a workaround by creating geometry within the model that had only a single dimension ex: (0,0,34) in order to force the change to the bounding box.